# about partition of set and change the index

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Assume $\{D_{r}\colon \ r\in\mathbb R\}$ be a partition of the set $D.$ Let $c$ be the cardinality of $\mathbb R.$ Since we know there exists a bijection between $c$ and $\mathbb R.$ So, we can write the above partition as $\{D_{\xi}\colon \ \xi<c\}.$ I think, it is easy and correct just making sure.

Comment: Yes, you can use any index set of the same cardinality.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you. assume I am writing a proof and I use $\{D_{r}\colon \ r\in\mathbb R\}$ and for some reason I have to change to $\{D_{\xi}\colon \ \xi<c\}$ . Mathematical, it is correct. Right?

Comment: Yes, there should be no problem with that.